# Read OpenstreetMap tags using GDAL

Tags: python, openstreetmap, gdal, shapefile

I am trying to extract data from OpenstreetMaps using exported shapefiles and GDAL Python library, however I cant find tag information in none of officially exported OpenstreetMap files.
Has anyone ever had similar issue?

Comment: There are no "official" shapefile files for OpenStreetMap. Please add some information where you did get your shapefiles.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not giving complete details. I am mainly downloading shapefiles from Geofabrik and other sites that are specified here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Download_shapefiles